# Spring batch doesn't execute flow in parallel mode.

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Spring batch doesn't execute flow in parallel mode. What am I doing wrong?

```
<split id="preprocessingStep" next="decompress">
        <flow>
            <step id="step11" next="step22">
                <tasklet ref="my1" />
            </step>

            <step id="step22">
                <tasklet ref="my2" />
            </step>

        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="step33">
                <tasklet ref="my3" />
            </step>
        </flow>
</split>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is because you use one-thread task executor. Try to add

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"
```

and change line to

```
   <split id="preprocessingStep" task-executor="taskExecutor" next="decompress">
```

to your config.